# How to get the onesignal notification from webview to andriod native notification

Tags: android, webview, onesignal

I am build an app based on webView. the website is already functional with oneSignal Notification  (website is codeignator based). I want the same notifications to be thrown to the users of that APP webView.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up push notifications for each channel (i.e: Web and Mobile). We have SDKs for both platforms making it easy to seamlessly send to both.

Read more [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk-setup)